# Why is constraint not working for UIView but works for UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, constraints

I have a simple (complete) example here which seems very odd, but surely im just missing something small... right? Can you help debug the simple code below. This code makes the aView disappear, but when if I put the aLabel in the constraint where the aView is, it works perfect. Why? Thanks for any input, this seems crazy to me.

austin

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 30)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:aView];

UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 30)];
aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
aLabel.text = @"Label";
aLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:aLabel];

NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:aView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintWithItem:aView
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
               toItem:self.view
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
               multiplier:1.0
               constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the line     `aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`
is making the view's size zero.. So you got to add these lines of code :

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:aView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:100];
[aView addConstraint:widthConstraint];


NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:aView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
[aView addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple. Certain objects, like UILabels have an intrinsic size based on their contained text, UIViews don't. So, since you didn't set a size for your UIView, its size is 0. You need to add either size constraints, or pin the view to the sides of its superview (or other views in the same view hierarchy).

Comment: I thought the frame gave it "size"...?

Comment: @user273312 When you're using auto layout, you shouldn't set any frames.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, setting all 4 constraints (left, right, top, bottom) solves the problem as well. Width and height are then adjusted and the UIView will be stretched accordingly. Note that all four constraints must be set.